# Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix - small variance

Tags: variance, model, convergence, glmmtmb

I want to see the differences between the 6 conditions regarding a centralization index (CI). 
I am trying to GLMM using the package glmmTMB in R but the following warning appears

Warning messages:
1: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')

I have a large data set (result of a boostrap), and the interactions 2 groups (big, small) and 3 distances (3lo, 7lo, 7up) hence, 6 conditions.

I am using negative binomial, having mean as weight (since CI is calculated by max-mean). Residual plots show little variance (which makes sense looking into CI values), also in agreement with underdispersion.

[image]

....

[image]

I tried to transform CI (sqrt and log) but variance is the same.
At some point I gave up on modelling and calculated a quick KW and pairwaise but all values were 2e-16 for all interactions.

Troubleshooting page is not helping either, perhaps as I am not versed in stats and be missing some basics.

Any comment, suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Whenever I've seen this error message, it's because of something like one variable being too similar to another, or an over-specification of random effects.   I would start by checking out the correlation between predictor variables (and interactions).

Comment: Thank you Paul Hewson. I tested for multicovariance, using vif, but values were below 10:                                                                                              
                 GVIF Df GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
group             3  1        1.732051
distance          4  2        1.414214
group:distance    8  2        1.681793                                                                                  Even when I box plot my data, you can see that each condition is different, but CI values are all between 0.13 and 0.30

Comment: OK, I know it's a different package, but there are some comments on similar problems for the lme4 package here: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html

Comment: Thank you! I am starting to look also to brms.